# Word choice for people who dont help

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

I have been wondering lately about what should we call a person who doesn't help. I.e. what is the word opposite to helpful?

Comment: There are quite a few differences. Do you mean: Not helpful because: not participating in being helpful (and that: willfully refusing maliciously, willfully refusing on principal); actively being malicious; trying to be helpful but doing more harm than good...

Comment: initially i just meant not participating. But now since you have mentioned it, please tell me the exact word for the other one too :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189857/what-are-good-men-that-do-nothing-called

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding facetious, the obvious choice would be **[unhelpful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unhelpful?searchDictCode=all)**:

> Not helpful

Comment: Hindrance is surely negative, while unhelpful is neutral?  Though I'd admit that in many situations [e.g. with an unhelpful official at a check-in desk] they amount to the same thing.

Comment: @DavidGarner The problem is with the definition (interpretation) of "antonym." See also: my comment at Robbie.

Comment: @DavidGarner that's an interesting and of course completely valid nuance,   especially as I seem to have overlooked the OP's request for helpful's 'opposite' in my haste to be facetious :)

Answer (score 0):

A hindrance.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hindrance

*a person or thing that hinders.*

Comment: Hmm... That's the problem with "antonyms" -- polar or diametrical! :)

Comment: Hmm… You've confused _me_ now:) http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/polar

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation - for example, after some kind of mishap - I would choose the noun bystander.

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELU. You may find useful hints here: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. After reading it you may think about investing a little more into your answer so it is more useful to the site users.