# What would you call a person that is so scared of losing their own life that they will go so far as to risk the lives of others?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What would you call a person that is so scared of losing their own life that they will go so far as to risk the lives of others? I'm trying to think of a word that expresses the meaning of someone who is selfish like that, but I don't want to use the words selfish or self-centered.  Writing an essay on the Holocaust; please help!

Comment: A ***coward***, surely?

Comment: A friend of mine said that too, and I thought it was a good one but is there a more direct definition?

Comment: Actually, "normal" comes pretty close.  It takes a fair amount of courage to resist the temptation you describe.

Comment: I'm describing why the Nazis were able to kill millions of Jews and one of my reasons is that many of the outlying countries or bystanders were to afraid to stand up and fight back.

Comment: That is an extremely interesting topic (and one that I have some strong opinions regarding), but, alas, one that needs to be called off-topic before it devolves into a fist-fight.  Perhaps someone here can recommend another venue for the discussion.

Comment: ***Desperate***, perhaps. If you've got nothing left to lose you might risk anything, including others' lives, in a desperate attempt to save your own life.

Comment: ...although in the context of your question, ***indifferent***, meaning they (the other countries) just didn't care, or care enough.

Comment: Brigid Brophy:  "Whenever people say, 'We mustn't be sentimental,' you can take it they are about to do something cruel. And if they add, 'We must be realistic,' they mean they are going to make money out of it."

Comment: @Abbey If that's what you're looking for, perhaps *[The Bystander Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect)* will suit? The effect gained particular notoriety after the [murder of Kitty Genovese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Kitty_Genovese). But note that the motivation underlying the effect isn't cowardice, [erroneous] delegation of responsibility.

Comment: Related: [“good men that do nothing”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189857/what-are-good-men-that-do-nothing-called)

Answer (score 2):

Spineless.  Lets put it into a sentence .That spineless Captain that sneaked of the Cruise Ship before it capsized got thrown in jail.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a combination of words to adequately explain the depth of meaning you are looking for.  Coward, fainthearted, invertebrate, recreant (though this usually means with intent...) are just a few.

Most were so fearful for the lives of their own that they would rather turn a blind eye to the atrocities occurring right in front of them.  It's nothing new and still happens with alarming frequency today.