# Looking for a specific synonym of "selfish"

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives, personality

A word or phrase that describes best a specific type of person or their behavior. The type of person that would not act upon a threat if said threat is not affecting their personal well-being directly.

Context: "Global warming becomes my problem only if I decide to believe I'll live long enough to see the consequences of it."

Proposals that are tightly related to the given context are more than welcome!

Comment: "Egoistic" may work in some contexts.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/selfish

Comment: [Good men who do nothing.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189857/what-are-good-men-that-do-nothing-called)

Comment: @Mazura, can you please turn your comment into an answer. I'd like to accept it. Outstanding.

Comment: Then we should close it as a dupe.

Comment: @Mazura, I wouldn't say the question is a duplicate. We arrived at the same answer because of my personal preference. If we mark it as a duplicate it wouldn't be fair for everyone who took the time to submit an answer.

Comment: I was honestly never completely satisfied by those answers. But my question doesn't conform to the current method of SWRs, so I'll leave this all up to the community at this point. Yours is on its way to being closed anyway. probably needs the phrase tag (and I'm not sure what else they want)

Comment: The other option is to upvote my question ;) and then self answer yours. I'd be interested to know what words from that page you use.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for an adjective, **self-centered** is a good option:

From Merriam Webster:

> self-centered
>
> 2 : concerned solely with one's own desires, needs, or interests.

e.g. He's so self-centered he doesn't consider global warming a threat unless it affects him directly.

Answer (score 1):

**self-interest**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Self+interest)

> n
>   1. one's personal interest or advantage
>   2. the act or an instance of pursuing one's own interest

As in:

> "Global warming becomes a **self interest** if I decide to believe
>   I'll live long enough to see the consequences of it."

Answer (score 0):

If I was in a particularly wordy and euphemistic mood, I would describe that person as "pursuing a policy of personal isolationism".
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/isolationism
Welcome to the community!