# What's a word to describe the fear of social embarrassment in overreacting to a situation? In regard to coronavirus

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word to describe the fear of social embarrassment in overreacting to a situation?

For example, *because of X*, none of the offices in my work building have gone remote, because nobody wants to be the first to do so. Nobody wants to risk being embarrassed by being thought to have overreacted to the coronavirus pandemic.

Comment: I would use two words: "lethal foolishness".

Comment: A parallel: on 9/11 it was those who broke the conventions who lived to tell the tale.

Comment: What is the basis for closing this question? If we don't inform the OP,  how can they improve it? Is it because it requires a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag? The link to "update the question" is not specific, and will no doubt confuse the author. Is it closed based on SWR always being considered as POB?

Comment: *Due to their [blank] none of the offices in my work building have gone remote because ...* - the word is ***hubris*** : "arrogance or excessive pride, often leading to a person's downfall" – [grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/usage/hubris/)

Comment: VTRO because example usage is noted ^^, you guys just weren't using your imagination.

Comment: @Rattler - Example sentences with a blank are my preferred example usage, but it IS NOT a hard requirement. I hesitate to add the one I made because *due to their* calls for no other word IMO.

Answer (score 7):

I would use 2 words...

***Herd behavior***

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior)

> **Herd behavior** is the behavior of individuals in a group acting collectively without centralized direction. Herd behavior occurs in animals in herds, packs, bird flocks, fish schools and so on, as well as in humans in demonstrations, riots and general strikes,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior) sporting events, religious gatherings, episodes of mob violence ***and everyday decision-making, judgement and opinion-forming.***

In other words...no explicit direction has been given by management, but workers interpret the culture that way.

and from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/herd_mentality), also 2 words:

> **Herd mentality**
>   The tendency for people's behavior or beliefs to conform to those of the group to which they belong.

Comment: Or [**herd mentality**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/herd_mentality) which has a dictionary entry.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another relevant one, from [the Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/bystander-effect):

> **Bystander effect**, the inhibiting influence of the presence of others on a person’s willingness to help someone in need. Research has shown that, even in an emergency, a bystander is less likely to extend help when he or she is in the real or imagined presence of others than when he or she is alone.

In the case of your office, it sounds like nobody is in immediate/direct need. However, everyone is acting as a bystanders to each other -- one person/one office sees that a second person/second office is continuing to come in to work, and so the first person/first office continues to do so as well. And this continues between all people/offices so that **everyone ends up staying because it looks like no one is leaving**.

Comment: [The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193321/68817)